# Linux IDE choice for existing generic open source project

Tags: c++, linux

I am having problems with wpa_supplicant not being able to authenticate to my AP on my current USB WIFI card, so I've decided to try to debug and see what's going wrong, and maybe I can make it work. In this process I would like to be able to debug the app.

I'm not that proficient in linux IDEs. Can you recommend me an IDE that has a way to import an open source project and magically make it appear in the IDE so I can build and execute it?

Comment: It highly depends on what IDE you have.

Comment: You can try KDevelop 4, it's relatively easy to make it work on almost any codebase. Also, there is Linux Kernel Developing plugin, which might be handy. It's not in official repository though, so you'd need to compile it manually.

Comment: You could just use a plain editor (like `emacs` or `gedit`, or perhaps `geany`) and compile the code with `make`. And you first should try to compile successfully the free software you want to improve. My advice is to learn to use `emacs`

Comment: It looks like you need debugger, and not IDE. Application may be built from makefile, with debug information. Standard Linux way is using command line gdb, or some graphic gdb wrapper, like Kdbg.

Comment: And your Wifi card issue might be a bug in some kernel module, and debugging these is more complex than debugging user-level applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try QtCreator IDE. The efforts of getting a "make"-based project into QtCreator are acceptable. If the project uses CMake as a build system, support is even better.

For generic projects: 
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.5/creator-project-generic.html

The IDE has everything you need, including debugger (gdb) and profiling (valgrind) support.

Comment: Basile: Yeah, I was thinking of first figuring out why the application seems to stop in the middle of the authentication with the access point, and to start with I'd go with trying to debug the application as to see if it's something wrong there. If it is the kernel module then I'll try to debug that one.

I think I'll just go with compiling with debug-information and then use kdbg or gdb to figure out what goes wrong.


Thanks for your info, everyone, I feel I've gotten off to a start :)